# NumberFormatException: Invalid int: res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png

Tags: android, android-resources, numberformatexception

Every time I tried running my app this error occurred. When I check **Logcat** I got these errors:

```
01-01 01:57:04.260 648-942/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-01 01:57:08.390 3836-3836/payments.banamex.citi.com.banamexpayments E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 01:57:09.000 3836-3836/payments.banamex.citi.com.banamexpayments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.infonet.emonitor.ControlApplication: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png"
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
        at com.example.infonet.emonitor.ControlApplication.onCreate(ControlApplication.java:20)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1000)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-01 01:57:12.920 648-749/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-01 01:57:15.620 1905-1905/com.android.launcher E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute.
```

Below is the **ControlApplication.java**

**ControlApplication.java:**

```
package com.example.infonet.emonitor;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.infonet.emonitor.util.Waiter;

public class ControlApplication extends Application {
    private static int IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES = 2;
    private static final String TAG = ControlApplication.class.getName();
    String app_timeout = "";
    private Context mContext;
    private Waiter waiter;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting application" + toString());
        this.app_timeout = getResources().getString(C0105R.string.app_timeout);
        if (this.app_timeout != null) {
            IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES = Integer.parseInt(this.app_timeout);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Application TimeOut " + IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES + " Minutes");
        this.mContext = getBaseContext();
        this.waiter = new Waiter(this.mContext, (long) ((IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES * 60) * 1000));
        this.waiter.start();
    }

    public void touch() {
        this.waiter.touch();
    }
}
```

Please, what does all these errors means. I've tried all possible means to rectify the issues but to no avail.

Comment: Please show `ControlApplication.onCreate`

Comment: Has `res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png` recently been added, deleted, renamed, or moved?  I would check on this.

Comment: Please add the `java` class to give you a proper soultion

Comment: @AbhinavSuman, I have updated it.

Comment: What you are trying to do with this code      
this.app_timeout = getResources().getString(C0105R.string.app_timeout);
        if (this.app_timeout != null) {
            IDLE_DELAY_MINUTES = Integer.parseInt(this.app_timeout);
        }

Comment: Whatever `C0105R.string.app_timeout` is, it's the resource ID for a drawable, currently. If that's a typo, and you meant `R.string.app_timeout`, then clean/rebuild your project. If that's not a typo, then it seems that you're somehow storing resource IDs in your own class, which you absolutely should not do. Those must be generated by the build system, and you need to use the generated `R` class, as they can change each build. In any case, there's no need to keep that as a `<string>`, and then parse it. Change your resource to an `<integer>,` and use `getResources().getInteger()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your stacktrace

```
at com.example.infonet.emonitor.ControlApplication.onCreate(ControlApplication.java:20)
```

You have written

```
Integer.parseInt("res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png")
```

I.e. `Integer.parseInt(this.app_timeout);`

Which is not how to get a resource ID from a file.

You can simply reference `R.drawable.ic_laucher_background`, which is an integer already, if that was the intention, but it seems you are trying to get a timeout value, not an image.

---

Specifically, this results in true

```
getResources().getString(C0105R.string.app_timeout)
    .equals("res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png");
```

I do not know what `C0105R` is supposed to be, but that looks suspect

---

Basically, if you did not intend for this to happen, you have a few options

1. You need to correct the value of `app_timeout` in `strings.xml`, or that `C0105R` file
2. You need to run `./gradlew clean` from the terminal and rebuild the app
3. Change your resource to an `<integer>`, not a `<string>`
4. Store the timeout as a `public static int` in the Application class, not a XML value

Comment: please take a look at ControlApplication.java which I have included in the post. Thanks.